# Gem::RemoteFetcher::FetchError: SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=SSLv3 read

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, windows

I am trying to install ruby on rails but I keep on getting so many errors when I am trying to create an application.

Here is what I did on my Windows machine:

1) Downloaded `railsinstaller-3.0.0.exe` software
2) Installed Rails on my machine.
3) Verified that installation is successful:

> E:\Rails>ruby -v ruby 2.0.0p598 (2014-11-13) [i386-mingw32]
>
> E:\Rails>sqlite3 --version
>   3.8.7.2 2014-11-18 20:57:56 2ab564bf9655b7c7b97ab85cafc8a48329b27f93
>
> E:\Rails>rails -v DL is deprecated, please use Fiddle Rails 4.1.8

Now when I am trying to create an application I am getting below exception:

Command used is: `rails new blog`

```
         run  bundle install
DL is deprecated, please use Fiddle
Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/...........
Fetching additional metadata from https://rubygems.org/..
Resolving dependencies...

Gem::RemoteFetcher::FetchError: SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=SSLv3 read server certificate B: certificate verify failed (https://rubygems.org/gems/rake-10.4.2.gem)
An error occurred while installing rake (10.4.2), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install rake -v '10.4.2'` succeeds before bundling.
```

Now I tried to run this command - `gem install rake -v '10.4.2'`, I started getting below error now:

```
E:\Rails>gem install rake -v '10.4.2'
ERROR:  Could not find a valid gem 'rake' (= 10.4.2), here is why:
          Unable to download data from https://rubygems.org/ - SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=SSLv3 read server certificate B: certificate verify failed (https://rubygems.org/specs.4.8.gz)
```

I am completely stuck here, can you please tell where I am making mistake in this installation? I tried various options given in SO but I am failing all the times.

If I try to start the server then I am getting below exception:

```
E:\Rails> cd blog
E:\Rails\blog>rails server
Could not find gem 'tzinfo-data (>= 0) x86-mingw32' in the gems available on this machine.
Run `bundle install` to install missing gems.
```

Now if I run `bundle install` I am getting new error:

```
E:\Rails\blog>bundle install
DL is deprecated, please use Fiddle
Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/...........
Fetching additional metadata from https://rubygems.org/..
Resolving dependencies...

Gem::RemoteFetcher::FetchError: SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=SSLv3 read server certificate B: certificate verify failed (https://rubygems.org/gems/rake-10.4.2.gem)
An error occurred while installing rake (10.4.2), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install rake -v '10.4.2'` succeeds before bundling.
```

Again if I try to install rake I am getting new exception:

```
E:\Rails\blog>gem install rake -v '10.4.2'
ERROR:  Could not find a valid gem 'rake' (= 10.4.2), here is why:
          Unable to download data from https://rubygems.org/ - SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=SSLv3 read server certificate B: certificate verify failed (https://rubygems.org/specs.4.8.gz)
```

I am trying this for the past 2 days, but still I a not able to understand where I am doing mistake in installation.

Comment: The answer to this problem seems to be pretty well documented in the linked gist.

https://gist.github.com/luislavena/f064211759ee0f806c88

Answer (score 3):

Update your GemFile:
from

```
https://rubygems.org
```

to

```
http://rubygems.org
```

Comment: This solution is a temporary workaround, but is an insecure recommendation and is nowhere near a permanent fix.

Answer (score 2):

`gem update --system` will install the latest version of Rubygems, including the correct up-to-date trust certificates.

Answer (score 0):

**How to add Trust Certificate in Ruby**

The solution for `SL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=SSLv3 read server certificate B: certificate verify failed` is here: [How to Manually add Trust Certificate](https://gist.github.com/luislavena/f064211759ee0f806c88)

---

Thanks for @luislavena solution & @BenY for answer.

Answer (score 0):

D:\Ruby\blog>gem source
*** CURRENT SOURCES ***

http://rubygems.org/

D:\Ruby\blog>bundle install
Fetching source index from https://rubygems.org/

Retrying fetcher due to error (2/4): Bundler::Fetcher::CertificateFailureError Could not verify the SSL certificate for https://rubygems.org/.

The gem source already shows from http://rubygems.org,but when I do the "bundle install", it still shows fetching source index from https://rubygems.org/, so weird.

Comment: This seems to be more of a comment on the OPs question than a practical answer.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I solve this issue with a couple of steps

Step 1. Download RubyGems is package management from [Here](https://rubygems.org/pages/download)

Step 2. Unpack into a directory and cd there

Step 3. Install with: `ruby setup.rb`

Step 4. Run `gem install rails`

**This step solves the issue for me!**